# Converting geotags to name and adding the names to images for fast search

Tags: windows, gps, geo-location, metadata, exif

Let's say I have a geo-tagged photo (see attached example with predefined EXIF: GPSLongitude and EXIF:GPSLatitude).
I wanna make a match between GPS coordinates and the designated name of the place.
The below example photo has been already tagged with the name of the place in EXIF:UserComment.
But let's just imagine that the tag EXIF:UserComment is missing, so I need to add it up somehow in order to be able to search by keyword name later (without bothering about knowing the GPS-coordinates of the place).

I would be satisfied even if GPS coordinates could be matched manually with a place by direct input of its name vs the coordinates (with allowed error). However as I was told some programs can do it automatically by loading the data from Google Maps or alike. One of such programs is the following: https://sourceforge.net/projects/geotag/
However the comments below the download link say that some users experience an issue with the app as it just stops working. Unfortunately it's got frozen on my notebook too. So I am curious if there are any other apps that can do the same?

As I said before, ideally the program must grab the GPS-coordinates, automatically convert them into the tag name and write it within EXIF:UserComment or any other tag, so that later I could search for any photos by keyword with the name of the place.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What OS must it run on? If Linux is OK: for me that task is accomplished by a "tiny little shell script" utilizing a Niminatim Web-API and two command-line tools: `jhead` (to extract the coordinates from Exif) and `exiftool` (to write comments to the Exif headers). The script does some other things for me, but I could extract those parts for you.

Comment: It's either Windows or Android actually

Comment: With Windows I cannot help (threw my last out of the same before it became 95, so almost 30 years ago). For Android, maybe [one of these apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_1044) can help? But that would be manual work. I did not try any of them, so I cannot say which one would work (best).